# how to get scheme from another app in android

Tags: android, url-scheme

so android lets you to do deep linking by putting scheme in your manifest file. is there a way to get list of schemes from the apps installed on your device? there should be a way to get this information because whoever calls this scheme is coming from outside anyway.

i've tried to get list of installed apps but can't find any info about scheme

Thanks!